# Jenkins plugin or option to report reoccuring failed tests long period

Tags: java, jenkins

For a batch of around 3000 unit/integration (PlSQL) tests we daily run a build for 3 versions of the code. Each week some tests have to be looked at and fixed. Only now I have the feeling that in the last 2 years I mainly see the same tests failing over and over again. Sometimes I have to fix them, sometimes someone else, so it is almost never that you see that same test frequent and it is almost impossible to spot failing tests over a longer period.

Minimal goal: Report all failing tests of all builds to 1 single file with the date for a longer period (year(s)).
Nice to have:

- Analysis tools that go with a report
- Being able to spot a reoccuring failing test and notify teammembers.

Does someone know of a good plugin or option within Jenkins that is able to do this?

Alternative idea: once per day kick of a script that scans the test result txt. files and adds them to 1 file.

Comment: Have you tried [Build Failure Analyzer](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-failure-analyzer/), with a MongoDB datastore ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it (we have PlSQL), but it publishes complete results which I still have to analyse myself and is per build. I was looking for a solution that bundles all failed test of all builds in 1 file to analyse.